# How can I select a specific PCL profile (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I need to use a specific Portable class library profile (111) and the default is 259. I have looked into the library section of the PCL's properties but 259 and 111 seem to have the same supported platforms selected so i cant seem to change between them using that. I need 111 because "brutile" a nuget package I need to use, requires that for it to be installed. The exact error output being

"Error Could not install package 'BruTile 0.21.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

Also this is a screenshot of the supported platforms that profile 259 and 111 both support. 
*note: Using visual studio 2017

[image: ds]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference between profile 111 and 259 is 259 supports silverlight projects.  I suspect you did not install the silverlight sdk or the windows 8.1 sdk so you do not have the option to uncheck them.

One option is to backup your csproj file and edit it.  Search for Profile259 and change it to Profile111.  Then reload your project.  (the back up is case something goes wrong and you cant open the project afterwards).  I think you will be able to use the Nuget package after that

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'l try these suggestions tomorrow and get back to you!

Comment: Installing both those SDKs didn't make them show in the 'change supported targets' options but changing the profile manually in the .csproj has allowed me to install Brutile! Thankyou!